# Placing an alert on select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form with a select and a number of options. within the options depending on which one you select it will show a different form.

My query is if a user begins filling out a form and then go to select another form I need add an alert when selecting another option and if they say yes then clear the form they have begun filling out.

Is this even possible?

```
$("select").change(function () {
$('div.box').hide();
    $('div.box.'+$(this).val()).show();
});


<h2>SELECT YOUR TEST!</h2>

                <select id=a>
                    <option value="chem">Chemical Analysis Testing Request Form</option>
                    <option value="fat">Fatigue Testing Request Form</option>
                    <option value="hard">Hardness Testing Request Form</option>
                    <option value="neutral">Neutral Salt Spray Testing Request Form</option>
                    <option value="stress">Stress Corrosion Testing Request Form</option>
                    <option value="tensile">Tensile Testing Request Form</option>
                </select>                             





                <!-- Test One -->


                <div class="chem box">

                <h2>Chemical Analysis Testing Request Form</h2>


                <label>Accreditation / Approval required:</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="ISO17025/UKAS">ISO17025/UKAS<br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Nacap">Nacap <br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="other">Other 
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Material / Allow type:</label>
                <input type="text">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>                
                <label>Can a Drawing be Supplied:</label><br>


                Yes<input type="radio" onclick="yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"> 
                No<input type="radio" onclick="yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck">

                <br>       

                <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">               
                Image upload: <input type='file' id='yes' name='yes'><br>
                </div>

                <div id="ifNo" style="display:none">
                If no can you sepcify form and dimensions:<br>
                <textarea type='text' id='other3' name='other3'></textarea><br>






                </div>
```

Here is a demo: [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u87hfens/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/u87hfens/13/) and example with clear form [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u87hfens/22/)

```
var isFormChanged = false;
$("select").change(function () {
    var type = $(this).val();
if(isFormChanged)
{
 var sure= confirm ('Your changes will be lost, proceed?');
    if(sure)
    {
        $('div.box.active').find('input[type=text]').val('');
        $('div.box.active').find('input[type=radio],[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
       showForm(type);

    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
   showForm(type); 

});

function showForm(type)
{
    $('div.box').removeClass('active').hide();

    $('div.box.'+type).show().addClass('active');
    isFormChanged = false;
}

$('div.box').find('input').on('change',function(){
isFormChanged = true;
});
```

Comment: the warning works perfectly, However the information is still there if you go back to the form you had been filling in?

Comment: Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/u87hfens/22/ on the active form you add the class, active, before form is hidden, it clears input type text, and reset radio and checkbox. When form is hidden class is removed again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a confirm box:

```
if ( confirm("Do you want to clear the form") ) {
    // process logic for hiding and showing new forms
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u87hfens/16/)

If you do not want to use the built in confirmations, then you will either need to design your own popup, or use something like a jQuery UI Dialog box.

Comment: I am not fussed about the look of the alert that can be dealt with, but your example is giving the confirm box even when I select the form for the first time?

Comment: You can add a variable to track something like that. I will update the fiddle.